# Using Google Slides API is it possible to use the response from one request in all or any of the remaining requests during the same batch Update

Tags: google-apps-script

I created this code which creates a Google Slides table from a Spreadsheet.  But since I had to have the tableObjectId I did it in two batchUpdates.  So I'm wondering if it's possible to get the resp1.replies[0].creatTable.objectId from the first request which creates the table, into the requests for loading the cells all in the same batch update.

The Code:

```
function putTablesIntoSlides() {
  var pr=SlidesApp.openById('Presentation Id');
  var slide1_ObjectId=pr.getSlides()[1].getObjectId();
  Logger.log(slide1_ObjectId);
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet10');
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var v=rg.getValues();

  //Create Table
  var request1={"createTable": {"elementProperties":{"pageObjectId": slide1_ObjectId},"rows": v.length,"columns": v[0].length}};
  var resp1=Slides.Presentations.batchUpdate({requests:request1}, pr.getId());

  //Preparing the request for Adding Text into cells
  var request2=[];
  for(var i=0;i<v.length;i++) {
    for(var j=0;j<v[i].length;j++) {

      //Is there a way to get the replies[0].createTable.objectId from the create table request in the same batch update.
      request2.push({"insertText":{"objectId":resp1.replies[0].createTable.objectId,"cellLocation": {"rowIndex":i,"columnIndex":j},"text": v[i][j].toString()}});
    }
  }

  //Adding text
  var resp2=Slides.Presentations.batchUpdate({requests:request2}, pr.getId());   
}
```

> In other words is it possible to use the response from one request in any or all of the remaining requests during a single batch update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to run the batchUpdate method of Slides API of the following requests by one API call.

  1. Create new table.
  2. Put values.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Modififcation points:

- In this case, when new table is created, the object ID of created table can be set at the request body.
- Using the object ID, the values can be put to the table.
- [The official document](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request?#createtablerequest)says as follows.

  > **objectId**:
  >   A user-supplied object ID for the placeholder identified above that to be created onto a slide.
  >   If you specify an ID, it must be unique among all pages and page elements in the presentation. The ID must start with an alphanumeric character or an underscore (matches regex [a-zA-Z0-9_] ); remaining characters may include those as well as a hyphen or colon (matches regex [a-zA-Z0-9_-:] ). The length of the ID must not be less than 5 or greater than 50.
  >   If you don't specify an ID, a unique one is generated.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
//Create Table
var request1={"createTable": {"elementProperties":{"pageObjectId": slide1_ObjectId},"rows": v.length,"columns": v[0].length}};
var resp1=Slides.Presentations.batchUpdate({requests:request1}, pr.getId());

//Preparing the request for Adding Text into cells
var request2=[];
for(var i=0;i<v.length;i++) {
  for(var j=0;j<v[i].length;j++) {

    //Is there a way to get the replies[0].createTable.objectId from the create table request in the same batch update.
    request2.push({"insertText":{"objectId":resp1.replies[0].createTable.objectId,"cellLocation": {"rowIndex":i,"columnIndex":j},"text": v[i][j].toString()}});
  }
}
//Adding text
var resp2=Slides.Presentations.batchUpdate({requests:request2}, pr.getId());
```

To:

```
var tableObjectId = "sampleId1";  // Here, the object ID of table is set.

//Create Table
var requests = [{"createTable": {"objectId": tableObjectId, "elementProperties":{"pageObjectId": slide1_ObjectId},"rows": v.length,"columns": v[0].length}}];

//Preparing the request for Adding Text into cells
for(var i=0;i<v.length;i++) {
  for(var j=0;j<v[i].length;j++) {

    //Is there a way to get the replies[0].createTable.objectId from the create table request in the same batch update.
    requests.push({"insertText":{"objectId":tableObjectId,"cellLocation": {"rowIndex":i,"columnIndex":j},"text": v[i][j].toString()}});
  }
}
//Adding text
var resp = Slides.Presentations.batchUpdate({requests:requests}, pr.getId());
```

- In this case, as a sample object ID, `var tableObjectId = "sampleId1"` is used.

#### Reference:

- [CreateTableRequest](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request?#createtablerequest)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks.  Now that I think about that's probably why they did it that way.