# How can I replace text in Google Presentations with text from Google Sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs, google-slides

I'm really new to programming in Google Apps Script and I'm trying to replace some words in all my slides with some text from a spreadsheet. I was following an internet tutorial for a similar task, but for replacing data in a Google Docs. I thought it would be the same, but it isn't and I'm kinda lost now. I need to 'translate' this piece of code from Docs to replace text in Slides.

```
var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId()); 
var body = doc.getBody();
body.replaceText('name', name);
body.replaceText('adress', adress);
body.replaceText('date', date);
```

I know I read the slide by this:

```
var presentation = Slides.Presentations.get(copy.getId());
```

But I don't know how to do the same task from before, but with my slides. Can someone help?

Edit: I tried what @Kos suggested. Since I have to replace about 20 words, I tried to implement a for loop, but I still don't get my words replaced in the slide.

```
var dict = {'{{word1}}':word1,'{{word2}}':word2};
for(let i=0; i< dict.length; i++){
    const resource = {
      requests: [{
        replaceAllText: {
          replaceText: dict[dict[i]],
          containsText: { matchCase: true, text: dict[i] }
        }
      }]
    };
    Slides.Presentations.batchUpdate(resource, presentation.getId());
  }
```

Should I try a different approach for replacing these words?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to update/replace text in a specific slide?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66882362/is-it-possible-to-update-replace-text-in-a-specific-slide)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60289543/using-google-slides-api-is-it-possible-to-use-the-response-from-one-request-in-a

Comment: @Kos I tried your suggestion, but I'm getting nowhere with the problem because I have multiple words to change in multiple slides, and I don't get how I should implement it.